# Передача файла с Windows на Linux и обратно

Tags: windows, linux

Как лучше передавать файлы между двумя машинами в сети (туда-обратно)? Я пользую PSCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много способов это сделать:

1. [SCP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCP). Самый правильный метод, т.к. SSH есть практически на любой линуксовой машине. Протокол весьма стабильный.
2. [FTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP). Плюс - это практически стандартный интернетовский протокол. Работает стабильно, поддерживает докачку. Минусы: плохо дружит с национальными кодировками, требует доп.настройки для работы, очень желательно ставить клиента вроде FileZilla. К тому же FTP не позволяет кидать файлы в произвольный каталог на сервере.
3. [SMB](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMB)/CIFS. Одни сплошные минусы, но стандартен в Винде, да и то относительно, т.к. есть масса нюансов.
4. [NFS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System). Полагаю будет сложен в настройке, привинтить к винде сложно, но можно, а вот нужно ли?
5. Можно еще запустить какого-либо IM-клиента (напр., skype, icq) на каждой из машин и передавать файлы через него. Минусы - нужно одновременно иметь открытые сессии на обоих ПК (можно через RDP), безопасность IM-протоколов под вопросом (QIP вообще изначально файлы на свой сервер льет и уже потом дает ссылку на скачивание собеседнику). Из потенциальных плюсов - тот же QIP (старый) умеет качать файлы напрямую между компьютерами. Т.е. можно получить максимальную скорость скачивания. С другой стороны, если связь пойдет через И-нет, то скорость будет низкая.
6. прочие

Answer (score 2):

Я пожалуй добавлю, что можно воспользоваться готовым апачем на Lunux. Он практически во всех дистрибутивах установлен. Плюсы - прямое соединение, простота настройки, 100% поддерживается любым браузером. Минусы - нужен сторонний скрипт для заливки файлов на сервер. Остальное не существенно.

Ну и ИМХО не согласен, что "SMB/CIFS. Одни сплошные минусы". Сам давно и плодотворно использую. В закрытых сетях - прекрасный выход из положения. Если нет опыта настройки или неохота возиться - настраиваем через Webmin.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно очень быстро перекинуть небольщой файл, можно воспользовать возможеностями python:

1. cd /folder_with_my_file
2. python -m SimpleHTTPServer
3. с другой машины подключаемся браузером (порт 8000) и забираем файл

Answer (score 1):

Для таких целей очень удобна Samba, которая позволяет обращаться к сетевым дискам по протоколу SMB/CIFS. В сети много описаний по ее установке и настройке. Например: [настройка Samba](http://www.rhd.ru/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-AS-2.1-Manual/custom-guide/configuring-samba.html).